# Android Market - double screenshots in application description

Tags: android, google-play

Since yesterday, our application description on the Android Market web version contains two sets of screenshots: the 480x800 ones that we've uploaded, and another one of very small dimensions, that dosen't appear in the application's assets, so, not being able to remove them.

On devices with the regular market version it's only showing the right set, but with the new version 3.0.26, I can see all the 12 pictures(both sets), just like on the desktop browser.

After some research, I've found another two applications with the same problem([Android Fun Ringtones](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sancron.ringtones.sb.androidfunsb), [Android-Geister](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.android.inoe.geister), [BoggleDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.en.boogledroid)), but I suppose there are more; though, there are way more applications that are just fine.

So I was wondering if someone already found a fix for that, if there is something we can do (maybe use another resolution for the screenshots!?) or we should just wait for more changes from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the Market right now. My apps are entirely missing their banners and screenshots. They still show up on the publish page, but not in the Market. I hope they get it straightened out soon.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that for my app yesterday. It seems to have been fixed as of right now.